# Visual Studio 2017 XUnit doesn't discover tests

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, xunit

I am following along the examples in the APRESS "Building Web Applications with Visual Studio 2017" book.

He has the reader set up a testing project by hand as a C# Console Application.

I pulled down the code and opened up his solution.  I am comparing mine to his side by side:

[image]

All the Unit Testing Nuget packages are the same.
But when I build both solutions his Tests get discovered and mine do not.

[image]

All it should be doing at this point is discovering this:

```
    [Fact]
    public void FirstTest()
    {
        Assert.True(true);
    }
```

Everything looks the same.
I created the console project. Added the needed Nuget Packages. Created the needed references. Added the test.

I don't know what else it needs. I followed the directions exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your test class public.

```
public class TestCategory
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you.